# Where should I place all the configurations for my web site on Apache?

Tags: apache-http-server, ubuntu-server, configure

I have a web site on the Apache HTTP Server that's installed on the Ubuntu Server.
I create my own config file in the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mywiki.conf` where I added the `<VirtualHost>...</VirtualHost>` where I place all the configurations.

In the official Apache documentation it is always said that you put your configs to the `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` or sometimes to the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`.

I'm a little bit confused about this.
What is the proper place where I should put all the configurations for my web site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the tutorial
[How To Configure the Apache Web Server on an Ubuntu or Debian VPS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-the-apache-web-server-on-an-ubuntu-or-debian-vps).

Briefly, the `/etc/apache2` folder contains the config files and folders.

For defining the websites, the official word is to use these folders
(which you did):

> - **sites-available/**: This directory contains all of the virtual host files that define different web sites. These will establish which
>   content gets served for which requests. These are available
>   configurations, not active configurations.
> - **sites-enabled/**: This directory establishes which virtual host definitions are actually being used. Usually, this directory consists
>   of symbolic links to files defined in the "sites-available" directory.

Although, for your own small server where you're the only administrator,
nothing obliges you to be a stickler to these conventions,
or you could make your own.
You do not have to follow the conventions adopted by other people
on their setups, as long as everything works out to your satisfaction.
Apache does not oblige you to use the above folder setup.

Comment: But still, why do we need `000-default.conf` file?

Comment: `000-default.conf` is the file that controls the default Apache sample website and is enough for serving a single site. For servers with a single IP you can use it as a template to make your own `.conf` file.

Comment: And I don't have `/etc/apache2/conf.d/` btw. For me it's `conf-available` and `conf-enabled`. Are those folders locate inside the `conf.d` folder in some other distributions of Linux?

Comment: This folder structure has been introduced in the Debian/Ubuntu family as a more structured way of organizing your files. I haven't checked, but it might be less prevalent in other distributions.